# CLI layer Object^ to byte array conversion

Tags: visual-c++, managed-c++

I have C# sample application with code

```
SampleClass cls = new SampleClass();
byte[] b = new byte[] { 1, 2, 3 };
object obj = b;
cls.Send(obj);
```

SampleClass is seperate dll which is implemented using Managed C++(CLI).

Now in Send method i am doing following.

```
void Send(Object^ data)
{
    cli::array<System::Byte>^ b = data;  //it is giving error
}
```

How can i convert Object^ to cli::array^?

Answer (score 1):

```
   cli::array<System::Byte>^ b = data;  //it is giving error
```

It is a *compile* error.  That statement is not valid in C++/CLI, just like it is never valid in C#.  And you solve it the same way as you do in C#, you *must* use a cast to make the conversion.

That rule isn't there just to make your life difficult, a conversion like this is very risky and apt to throw an InvalidCastException.  Having to use a cast operator alerts the reader, helps you debug the program and convinces the compiler that you know what you're doing.

Casting managed object references in C++/CLI is done with the safe_cast<> keyword.  Fix:

```
   auto b = safe_cast<cli::array<System::Byte>^>(data);
```